# Setting function signature to custom type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a function with a signature

```
const updateMatrix = (m: number) => (i: number, j: number, value: number): void => {
```

However, I need to re-use the second function's signature in other parts of my code, so I set it to a type.

```
export type SetMatrixValue = (i: number, j: number, value: number) => void
```

How can I set the type of my updateMatrix function to match that of the SetMatrix Value type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the type of the second function using [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) utility (it is actually return type of `updateMatrix`):

```
const updateMatrix = (m: number) => (i: number, j: number, value: number): void => {}

type SetMatrixValue = ReturnType<typeof updateMatrix>; // (i: number, j: number, value: number) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBArgBwCYEMoFMCyaBOBLADxgF4YAKAWwC4Yw4KAjdHAShID5y8a7HmAaGACse9JjkEA3FABs46UX1Y1JIPEg4wA3jAC+AKH1QAngnQwAyuijYo+AgDVZ8kjABK1uDjAAVU+gAeEzMQADN4ZDQsXEJ2IA)

---

Answering original question:

```
type SetMatrixValue = (i: number, j: number, value: number) => void

const updateMatrix = (m: number): SetMatrixValue => (i, j, value) => { };
```

Comment: I want it the other way around, I want to be able to pass the type TO the function to serve as both its arguments and return type, so I can re-use it in other functions in my code.